# html to pdf convertion css not working

Tags: django, python-3.x

I try to convert the following page to pdf
[link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/P234b)

using xhtml2pdf library for python.
But the problem is the css styles are not working properly.
How can i solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write all css in header. Import will not work in pdf.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
```

this need to be change like following:

```
<style>
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.0.0 (https://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2018 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT 
 (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */:root{--blue:#007bff;--indigo:#6610f2;--purple:#6f42c1;--pink:#e83e8c;-- 
  red:#dc3545;--orange:#fd7e14;--yellow:#ffc107;--green:#28a745;-- 
  teal:#20c997;--cyan:#17a2b8;--white:#fff;--gray:#6c757d;--gray- 
  dark:#343a40;--primary:#007bff;--secondary:#6c757d;--success:#28a745;--
  ......
</style>
```

Comment: so i have to write the full bootstrap style sheet on html page ??